# What does it mean if GHCi doesn't declare a function type?

Tags: haskell

and I'm struggling to understand why this is wrong. GHCi hasn't been showing its function type or throwing an error which makes it hard for me to debug. Is there a reason: 1. Why it isn't throwing any error 2. What is making this code not work?

```
:{
let sumCircle [] = error "empty list";
    sumCircle [x] = 3.14159*x^2;
    sumCircle [x:restOfList] = sumCircle x + sumCircle restOfList
}:
```

Comment: The closing tag is `:}`, not `}:`. The colon is actually *not* really part of the encapsulation, it is used to "perform GHCi commands".

Comment: I.e. it's still waiting for you to close the block with `:}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your delimiter for the multi-line input is swapped. You need `:}` in order to close multi-line input, not `}:`. Remember, the colon (`:`) signals GHCi that the lines content isn't Haskell, but instead a GHCi-specific construct.

We can see that also at GHCi's prompt:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let sumCircle [] = error "empty list";
Prelude|     sumCircle [x] = 3.14159*x^2;
Prelude|     sumCircle [x:restOfList] = sumCircle x + sumCircle restOfList
Prelude| }:
Prelude|
```

Note that it's still `Prelude|`, not `Prelude>`. As soon as we use `:}` instead, we end up with the syntax error due to the `}:`:

```
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

And if we use the proper delimiter from the start, we end up with the expected type error:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let sumCircle [] = error "empty list";
Prelude|     sumCircle [x] = 3.14159*x^2;
Prelude|     sumCircle [x:restOfList] = sumCircle x + sumCircle restOfList
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:4:56: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
    * In the first argument of `sumCircle', namely `restOfList'
      In the second argument of `(+)', namely `sumCircle restOfList'
      In the expression: sumCircle x + sumCircle restOfList
    * Relevant bindings include
        restOfList :: [t] (bound at <interactive>:4:18)
        x :: t (bound at <interactive>:4:16)
        sumCircle :: t -> [t] (bound at <interactive>:2:5)
```

By the way, you can use `pi` instead of `3.1415926…`, and with `sum` and `map` you don't need explicit recursion, but that's for the later cleanup.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for that insight about the > and the |. That'll be real helpful in the future. Sorry for asking a stupid question but how would you change up the last statement to get the thing to work? I'm actually not understanding what I've written that's causing the issue

Comment: @HayashiEsme there are two mistakes at once. First of all, you need parentheses, e.g. `sumCircle (x:restOfList)`. Otherwise you will match a list _inside of a list_, e.g. `[[1,2,3,4,5]]`, where `x` is `1` and `[2,3,4,5]`. And next, well, `sumCircle x` in the last line expects `x` to be a list. But that would make `restOfList` a list of lists, which would beget `x` as list of lists, which makes `restOfList` a list of list of lists, which… you get it. `sumCircle` only works for lists, yet you try to use it on a single element. It gets a lot more clear if you use explicit type signatures.